# How to get the path/url of an api operation without the api suffix included in Azure api management?

Tags: azure-api-management, policy

I'm wondering of there is a way to get the operation path / url using a policy in API Management?

What i have been looking at so far is the context variables written between "@()" when trying to get specific values regarding the context of the api i'm currently working at.

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-request-headers).

I've been trying different stuff and the closest i could come to finding what i was looking for was this staement:

> @(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.ToString())

But as mentioned before that included the api suffix which in this case i want to exclude.

Comment: Maybe this will help: `@(context.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Url.Host.ToString())`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @MarkusMeyer, tried your suggestion, it was not quite what i was looking for, with that statement i get the base address, i 'm only looking for the opersation path. That is: "/getpersons/{attribute}"  for example.

Comment: So i tried out the "context.Operation" variables. those didnt work either. i thought:
@(context.Operation.UrlTemplate.ToString()) would work but when entering an apptribute it lonly gives me the Template without the given attribute... 

That is:

I get: /person/{attributeid}
Not: /person/10

Comment: Ok, so i think i really found it this time: @(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.ToString().Replace("[suffix]","")).

Comment: You could post it as answer to close this issue.

Comment: @JoeyCai Will do as soon as i've had a chance to test it out some more. ;)

Answer (score 1):

So I've tested the statement described in the comments above and its exactly what i was looking for.
This worked for me: @(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.ToString().Replace("[suffix]","")).

Comment: Not able to mark this as an answer within the first 48h as of posting the answer.